# is there a specific code or function to freeze a cell value for a specific time and then recalculate it after 5 mins?

Tags: excel, vba, dde

I have a set of live data (using DDE) shown on excel, I want to be able to freeze a specific cell (not allow it to update, because live data updates every second), and then enable it to update after a specific period of time 
what type of function should I use?

Comment: You would probably want to set up an if statement which says that the cell can't update until the other cells are updated. Do you have any code we can look at?

Comment: @Kyoujin ive used something like this, im new to the site and coding it self so sorry if it seems stupid 
Sub VBA_Calculate_Range()
    Range("T2:T36").Calculate
End Sub

Comment: is it in that range you want the one cell not to update? Try and give as much info as possible and I will try to help.

Comment: @Kyoujin yes, I want to "freeze" their values and then recalculate after 5 mins, sorry if im not clear.

Comment: I would really appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly what you are after I have created a rough guess, which will wait 5 minutes from when launched it will then add the range you mentioned and output it into cell A1. You will need to then mod that to your needs.

```
Sub CalcRange()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("sheet1")


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("05:00:00")

 Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell = "=SUM(T2:T36)"
End Sub
```